# Displayed Information

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am create an answer button. Cancel button not working properly.

```
        function Confirmation() {


        var txt;
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want an answer?){
            txt = "";
        } else {
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: It still displaying the answers  @TeeKea

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

When you call the function, call it like this: `onclick="return Confirmation('@("Ans"+i)')"`

Then, inside the function, do the following:

```
    function Confirmation(div) {
       if (confirm("Are you sure you want an answer? \n **Coins of 150 will get deducted** ")){
          document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = "";
          return true;
       } else {
          return false;
       }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise the following jQuery Solution:

```js
$(function() {
  function Confirmation(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var ans = $(this).attr("href");
    var result = confirm("Are you sure you want an answer? \n **Coins of 150 will get deducted**");
    if (result) {
      $(ans).show();
    }
  }

  $(".btn").click(Confirmation);
});
```

```css
.collapse {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#Ans0" id="Ans" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-info">Show Answer</a>
<div id="Ans0" class="collapse" style="border: 1px solid;font-weight:bold;">

  Answer: @item.answers

</div>
```

Since this is a Link, the default action is to navigate to the anchor. You need to halt this using `.preventDefault()` on the `click` event itself.

Next we need to know the target; this being the `href` attribute, we can collect that detail.

`confirm()` results in either `true` or `false` based on the users input. We can store this in a variable or use it in a `if` statement as needed. We can then perform an action based on that selection from the user. In this case, if the user hits `OK`, the result would equate to `true` and we can use `.show()` to reveal the answer. If it's collapsed, you can script it to be expanded.

**Side Note** In your loop, you assign `Ans` as the ID for each `<a>` and this is going to create issues later. Each HTML Element should have a unique ID attribute.

**Update** From your comment, it's not clear where `i` is defined. Please review your question and code, update it you need further help.

Comment: You forgot to add `onclick` in the html

Comment: @Rod I didn't. I assigned the click callback via jQuery.

Comment: if I added the `i` for the foreach loop to the answers from the database, it still displays the answers whenever i click on "Cancel"

Comment: @Rod please update your post with the new code you're using or post a MVCE.

Comment: It's in my questions

Comment: @Rod yot lost doesn't include updated code or complete example.